# Making asynchronous code cancellable

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have some time-consuming method:

```
public class TimeConsumingClass
{
   public void TimeConsumingMethod()
   {
      //let's imagine my method works this way
      for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
         Thread.Sleep();
   }
}
```

It was executed in main thread previously. Then I needed to call it in secondary thread to not block UI:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { new TimeConsumingClass().TimeConsumingMethod(); });
```

And now I need to make it possible to stop this method at any time. So I want to make my method treat CancellationToken somehow and at the same time I want to keep possibility to call this method synchronously (without CancellationToken). The best idea I came to is to add optional CancellationToken argument to my method which will be null by default (for synchronous calls):

```
public class TimeConsumingClass
{
   public void TimeConsumingMethod(CancellationToken cancellationToken = null)
   {
      //let's imagine my method works this way
      for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
      {
         if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
           return;
         Thread.Sleep();
      }
   }
}
```

But there was a lot of innovation in .NET multithreading recently and I have a feeling the is a better way to do what I am going to do. Is there one?

Comment: Without knowing the workload that is **actually** represented by `Thread.Sleep` this is an optimal solution.

Comment: Your question talks about making *asynchronous* code cancellable... but this looks entirely synchronous to me. Could you clarify please?

Comment: @JonSkeet, by asynchronous I meant my code is executed in non-main thread

Comment: @spender, are there any workload details which could change the answer? I could provide some :)

Comment: Looks like thats how they do it in the example on [How to: Cancel a Task and Its Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607.aspx)

Comment: @Idsa: That's not really what asynchronous means though. It's well worth investigating asynchrony in *much* more detail, as it could simplify your life considerably.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I agree but I didn't think of better question title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a more "modern" way to do it, your best bet is to study the new `async` and `await` keywords in c#.  They are by far the most straightforward way to implement asynchronicity.

You can find a good introduction to `async` and `await` here:

**Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

To find out how to report progress and cancel asynchronous methods, read here:

**Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs**
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/

To cancel tasks in the same style of the code you're using in your question, look here:

**Task Cancellation**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd997396(v=vs.100)