# How to make a C# method cancellable?

Tags: c#

I'm on a project coding a 4 axes robot arm.

I'm working on **Virtual Studio** and **coding in C#**. I'm **NEW** to C# so please be tolerant.

The robot came with a large .cs library and a Programming Manual with sample methods.

The sample interface :
[sample_interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwWWH.png)

I used cetains of these samples to build an **operation method** which makes the arm accomplishes repetitive movements for a chosen number of times. (I erased some movements here to avoid too much useless code) Here it comes :

```
private async void button_operation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int op_number;
            for (op_number = 0; op_number < Convert.ToInt32(textBox_operation.Text); op_number++) {

                int i;

                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    axis_list[i] = i;
                }

                v_dist[0] = 60;
                v_dist[1] = 10000;
                v_dist[2] = -1000;
                v_dist[3] = -8000;

                if ((int)g_handle != 0)
                {
                    zmcaux.ZAux_Direct_Base(g_handle, 4, axis_list);
                    zmcaux.ZAux_Direct_SetSpeed(g_handle, axis_list[0], 10000);
                    zmcaux.ZAux_Direct_MoveAbs(g_handle, 4, v_dist);
                    zmcaux.ZAux_Direct_GetIfIdle(g_handle, 3, ref idle_state[3]);

                    make_pause(g_handle, 3);

                    v_dist[0] = 50;
                    v_dist[2] = -1700;
                    v_dist[3] = -10550;

                    zmcaux.ZAux_Direct_MoveAbs(g_handle, 4, v_dist);
                    zmcaux.ZAux_Direct_GetIfIdle(g_handle, 3, ref idle_state[3]);

                    make_pause(g_handle, 3);

                    v_dist[0] = 60;
                    v_dist[2] = -1000;
                    v_dist[3] = -8000;

                    zmcaux.ZAux_Direct_MoveAbs(g_handle, 4, v_dist);
                    zmcaux.ZAux_Direct_GetIfIdle(g_handle, 3, ref idle_state[3]);

                    make_pause(g_handle, 3);
                }
            }
        }
```

The `make_pause()` method is to make the robot wait the end of a movement before beggining the next :

```
        {
            while (idle_state[iaxis] == 0)
                {
                    zmcaux.ZAux_Direct_GetIfIdle(g_handle, iaxis, ref idle_state[iaxis]);
                }
        }
```

By side, I also used another sample to add a **"STOP" button** but for this one, I **just had to copy** the whole method as it comes. Its role is to obviously cancel every movement. However, it's not working.

The sample method I used for the Stop Button :

```
        {
            if ((int)g_handle != 0)
            {
                zmcaux.ZAux_Direct_Rapidstop(g_handle,2); 
            }
        }
```

My first though is that my operation method construction does not allow another method call to cancel.
Thus, I made a **TEST button** to create a single movement just like on my sample project.
Problem is that the STOP button is still not working.

What am I missing ? Is there something wrong with the way I am building the methods or project ?

Thanks

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438937/making-asynchronous-code-cancellable

Comment: This question is impossible for us to answer, as we have no idea what robot you're programming, and have no idea what the library looks like and we know even less about how it works. And you're "technical description" of the problem (i.e. "However, it's not working") doesn't help is answer your question at all. You'll need to search out someone who knows the library, knows the robot and knows how to diagnose problems in it